# QT vs. Delphi and Align possibilities

Tags: delphi, qt, properties, alignment

I'm trying to figure out if there's anything in QT that is equivalent to Delphi's Align property possibilities like alTop, alClient, alRight and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's something better than alignment: [layouts](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/layout.html)! You can create layouts from the Qt Designer or from code.
My approach is to start with the smallest unit of grouping and add layouts and spacers as needed and finish with the window layout, which ensures that all the widgets resize with the window.